# Achilles throws "IllegalStateException: Unknown current type : java.util.Collection<org.example.AnInterface>"

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm using Achilles as an object mapper for Cassandra and generally it's working quite well, however Achilles is now throwing an IllegalStateException when the annotation processor is ran.

```
Error:java: Error while parsing: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown current type : java.util.Collection<org.example.AnInterface>
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.AnnotationTree.buildTree_Javac(AnnotationTree.java:370)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.AnnotationTree.buildFrom(AnnotationTree.java:304)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.FieldParser.parse(FieldParser.java:62)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.AbstractBeanParser.lambda$parseFields$315(AbstractBeanParser.java:65)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.AbstractBeanParser.parseFields(AbstractBeanParser.java:66)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.parser.EntityParser.parseEntity(EntityParser.java:45)
at info.archinnov.achilles.internals.apt.processors.meta.AchillesProcessor.lambda$discoverAndValidateTablesAndViews$651(AchillesProcessor.java:259)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
```

In the stacktrace, AnInterface is an interface that has an implementation named AnInterfaceImpl which is annotated with @UDT and @Table at the class level. The field which appears to be causing this is annotated with @Column and has the field signature `Collection<AnInterface>`.

Does anyone have any information on how I may be able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not expert in Achilles, but I think that `Collection` is too generic declaration & there could be `Set`, `List`, ... that are mapped differently to the underlying Cassandra types. Please use specific types, like, `List<AnInterface>`, that are matching to type of the Cassandra table.